# sql count() and *

Tags: php, sql, aggregate-functions

Is this possible in sql :

```
COUNT(ads.id) AS ads, *
```

If not, then what to use?  I'm using `LEFT JOIN`, there are two tables: `ads` and `ad`, but I'm not using `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT COUNT(ads.id) AS ads_count, 
       ads.* 
  FROM ...
```

It's not working.

Comment: Are you using a `GROUP BY`? What do you want your results to look like?

Comment: It's possible. What's the problem? Show the entire query and whatever error(s) you may be getting.

Comment: It's very hard to tell exactly what you're asking here.  Could you please clarify with more information?

Comment: If you actually tried it, you'd know you can.  You might need a `GROUP BY`, depending on the database though.

Comment: Maybe you are confusing the database by calling your table `ads` and also your column. Hard to tell without more information.

Comment: Ignoring SQL entirely for the moment, please explain in words what data you are trying to get. This should help clear things up!

Comment: @cute It would clear up a lot of confusion if you'd tell us what DBMS you're using.

Answer (score 4):

It's certainly possible to include a `*` in the SELECT list alongside *other columns*, in general. But `COUNT()` is an aggregate function, and the implication there is that you're grouping by every other column in the resultset, which is probably not true.

Whether or not that query will function may be heavily dependent on which DBMS you're using, which you haven't specified. In MS SQL Server, you *must* declare all non-aggregate columns in a GROUP BY clause, and `*` is not a valid member in a GROUP BY clause, hence in SQL Server that's an invalid query.

MySQL seems to have somewhat looser rules around grouping and using aggregate functions, so it's possible that query may be syntactically valid (I don't have a MySQL database handy to test it), but its results would almost certainly be indeterminate...

Comment: SQLite has the same "flexibility" about the `GROUP BY`, but it is ANSI to be able to omit columns from the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Is that so? What's the default behavior defined by ANSI for `SELECT colA, colB, colC, SUM(colD) FROM t GROUP BY colA`? That sort of non-specificity has always made me wary, but that might just be my SQL Server upbringing.

Comment: Believe me, I wish it weren't true -- especially when MySQL & SQLite return arbitrary values for the non-aggregate, non-GROUP BY columns.

Comment: It is as I feared! :) Anyrate, the problems with leaving columns out of the GROUP BY provide a nice framework for understanding what's going on in this question.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
-- test table
declare @T table(name varchar(10), number int)

select *, count(name)
from @T 
group by number, name
```

In MSSQL, if you **select *** then you would have to list all of the columns in the **group by**.

Of course the only counts that would be greater then 1 would be for duplicated rows.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT COUNT(ads.id) AS ads_count, 
       ads2.*
FROM table_name ads
JOIN table_name ads2
GROUP BY ads.id
```

`table_name` should be your table name.